# PHP Laravel custom sort by final and better time

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

i try to work this situation. i have table with results. until now i used ->orderBy('final') but i found out that is not working when i have same final time.

```
  Left time |  Right time  |  Final
0    24:45       24:22        24:45
1    24:85       21:84        24:85
2    24:44       25:12        25:12
3    25:12       21:78        25:12
4    38:12       25:99        38:12
```

problem is when i have equal final time like index [2],[3] and when is situation like that i want check better time **Left time** or **Right time** and sort them again..

so finally it must look like (index 2, 3 switch)

```
  Left time |  Right time  |  Final
0    24:45       24:22        24:45
1    24:85       21:84        24:85
2    25:12       21:78        25:12
3    24:44       25:12        25:12
4    38:12       25:99        38:12
```

Comment: You should be able to use `orderByRaw()` and add more than one column of sorting. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following

```
Model::orderByRaw("column1 DESC, column2 DESC");
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use orderBy multiple times.

```
MyTable::orderBy('column1', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('column2', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```